# Beta function in the large $N$ limit

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, renormalization, yang-mills, large-n

I am currently studying Quantum Field Theory in the large $N$ limit (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9601080) and I am trying to understand how to calculate RG $β$-function

[[image: large <span class=]$N$ β-function" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Am7g.png)

How can one reach to such expression from the relation 4.9?

[image]